# Mandrill: Queued mail for delivery, but 550 Bad Mailbox

Tags: php, email, outlook, smtp, mandrill

I use **Mandrill** to send my transactional emails. Several days ago I started to analyse bounces and found some interesting reports. Some of my hard bounces have  following messages simultaneously:

- `Queued mail for delivery`
- `smtp;550 5.1.1 RESOLVER.ADR.RecipNotFound; not found`

It seems that mailbox is invalid. To prove this, I tried to send an email using terminal:

```
$ telnet mx.example.com 25
Trying 100.100.100.100...
Connected to mx.example.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 mx.example.com Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service ready at Wed, 6 May 2015 20:01:56 +0300
HELO mx.example.com
250 mx.example.com Hello [200.200.200.200]
MAIL FROM: <noreply@mysite.com>
250 2.1.0 Sender OK
RCPT TO: <user@example.com>
250 2.1.5 Recipient OK
DATA
354 Start mail input; end with <CRLF>.<CRLF>
from: noreply@mysite.com
to: user@example.com
subject: test   

Hi!
.
250 2.6.0 <99534bb0-ed72-428b-a487-48aaac32ca11@tmh-srv080.hq.tmh.local> [InternalId=727698] Queued mail for delivery
QUIT
221 2.0.0 Service closing transmission channel
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

So, it seems, **Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service** does not check recipient, but push my message into the queue. Actually I could not get 550 code from mail server in terminal, but **Mandrill** could.

Any ideas how it is done in **Mandrill**? Is it possible to validate email when server uses **Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service**?

Comment: many mail servers will not longer validate emails while in the "sending" (e.g. they're accepting). it's far too easy for spammers to abuse. They'll simply accept everything, then trash it after the fact.

Comment: @MarcB you are right. But Mandrill somehow shows me bounces, hence it knows whether mailbox exists or not. How it is possible?

Comment: The reason they know that it's a bad mailbox is because they have bounce management. Which means you send an email to a box, then you get a mailer-daemon respond giving you all the errors. That's what they are doing processing the bounced email.

Comment: @Augwa thank you. This is exactly how it happens. In addition, it seems Mandrill uses [VERP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_envelope_return_path) or some related technic to get things done.